# Unable to change the time in requestLocationUpdates() method?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

Here I want to send latitude and longitude updates to server for each and every 5min,but in my  code i'm changing min time in requestLocationUpdates() method but its not changing.my appication sending updates to every 1min is fixed. see my code below

```
 @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //TODO do something useful
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Got in!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("Got in");

     Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        

        //---use the LocationManager class to obtain locations data---
        lm = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

      //---request for location updates using GPS---
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                2000,
                0,
                pendingIntent);     
        lm.requestLocationUpdates( 
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                2000, 
                0, 
                pendingIntent);

    return START_STICKY;
  }


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //---remove the pending intent---
    lm.removeUpdates(pendingIntent);

    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "onLocationChanged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "onProviderDisabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "onProviderEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStatusChanged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

}
```

can any one help me.thank you.

Comment: what you want to is ,to change the time i.e., 5min..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send GPS co-ordinates for every five  minutes then you have to write like this

```
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                5 * 60 * 1000,
                0,
                pendingIntent);     
 lm.requestLocationUpdates( 
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                5 * 60 * 1000, 
                0, 
                pendingIntent);
```